# Is there any possible way to check which Split() element is used?

Tags: c#, string, split, calculator

I have this code:

```
string expresie = Console.ReadLine();          
char[] separatori = {'+', '-'};
string[] elementeExpresie = expresie.Split(separatori);

int elem0 = int.Parse(elementeExpresie[0]);
int elem1 = int.Parse(elementeExpresie[1]);
int elem2 = int.Parse(elementeExpresie[2]);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int operatie1 = 0;

if (separatori[0] == '+')
{
    operatie1 = elem0+elem1;
}
else if (separatori[0] == '-')
{
    operatie1 = elem0-elem1;
}           
           
int operatie2 = 0;

if(separatori[1] == '+')
{
    operatie2 = operatie1+elem2;
}
else if(separatori[1] == '-')
{
    operatie2 = operatie1-elem2;
}

Console.WriteLine(operatie2);
```

I have to code a program similar to a calculator, where the user inserts an arithmetic expression in the console, and at the end, it has to show the results of the calculation. The second part of the code doesn't work, because I need to check which char[] element is used; the "+" or the "-". And that's actually my question: **Is there any possible way to check which Split() element is used?**

*Exemple:* `string mathExpression = "10 + 11 - 5"`

*Console output: 16*

PS: It's for a school homework and I need to use the `.split` method.

Comment: No, there's no way to tell which separator `string.Split` used. Can you split on whitespace instead, if the user always enters `1 + 2` and never `1+2`?

Comment: Split removes the separator used to split from the returned strings. You cannot use split to discover which separator has been used in the splitting process.

Comment: You should split on whitespace (just don't pass any parameters to `Split`) and then examine each part to determine if it's a number or an operator.

Comment: Instead of simply using `Split`, use a set of Regexes to *tokenize* your input.  For example, the tokens would end up as ("10", numeric), ("+", operator), ("11", numeric), ("-", operator), ("5", numeric).  Then, once you get the set of tokens, *parse* them into the expression you want

Comment: @Flydog57 *"it's for a school homework and I need to use the .split method."*

Comment: OK then, use something like `IndexOf` to find the location of the operators and glue things back together.  You can split on whitespace, but if someone enters `10 + 11 -5` bad things will happy.  This is a bit like saying "The assignment is to cook a turkey and I need to use a toaster"

Comment: Consider splitting on the operators, one at a time.  Consider `10+11-5-2+6+7-4`.  Splitting on the `+` gives `10`, `11-5-2`, `6`, `7-4`.  Then walk through the results looking to see if there's a remaining operator in the string or not.  If there is, split on it (so that `11-5-2` becomes `11`, `5` and `2`). It's a very complicated way of parsing that line

Comment: I'd say this is more of a puzzle rather than general implementaion. Since it's homework...maybe treat it like a puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to split on whitespace so you have a collection of operands and operators. Then you can do something like below:

```
string expression = Console.ReadLine();
string[] expParts = expression.Split();

int operand1 = int.Parse(expParts[0]);
string operator1 = expParts[1];
int operand2 = int.Parse(expParts[2]);
string operator2 = expParts[3];
int operand3 = int.Parse(expParts[4]);

int result = operand1;

if (operator1 == "+")
{
    result += operand2;
}
else if (operator1 == "-")
{
    result -= operand2;
}

if (operator2 == "+")
{
    result += operand3;
}
else if (operator2 == "-")
{
    result -= operand3;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The drawback here is that it requires a precise string format (`"10 + 11 - 5"`). If someone entered `"10+11-5"`, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your operators with padded operators, and split on the pad character.

For example

```
var pad = "\0";
var input = "1+2";
var operators = new string[] { "+", "-" };
foreach (var operator in operators)
{
    input = input.Replace(operator, pad + operator + pad);
}
var tokens = input.Split( new string[] { pad } , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Console.WriteLine(tokens[0]); // Outputs "1"
Console.WriteLine(tokens[1]); // Outputs "+"
Console.WriteLine(tokens[2]); // Outputs "2"
```